# USRP N210 B & F Lights

Tags: matlab, software-defined-radio, usrp

During setup of a USRP N210 on MATLAB's Communications Toolbox Support Package for USRP Radio, the initial test failed on "Receive the signal and verify the frequency of the tone" field. Afterword, MATLAB crashed and my USRPN210's led's swapped from D&F to B & F. I also can't get a successful ping or find my USRP with 'uhd_find_devices --args="addr=192.168.10.2"' now.

Aside from the USRP manual showing LED 'B' as a MIMO cable link, I haven't seen anything stating that the B & F combination indicates any known error. Did I somehow brick my USRP? If not, is there something else I should know about troubleshooting from here?

Here's a pic from MATLAB of the testing page minus my error (due to the crash).

[image]

Comment: In case you haven't done so already, I suggest contacting MathWorks and Ettus directly.

Comment: @MBaz thanks. I took the suggestion. It does look like the USRP is back to D&F only and ping-able on a fresh power cycle today, but I'm hesitant to run through Matlab again without an answer.